# Replacing elements of a 3D matrix in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, 3d, matrix, replace

I have a 3D matrix that consists of 3 matrices 500x500 elements. Now, I wanna take the third matrix and replace all its values that are, let's say, bigger than 100 with 0. If I have a matrix a, my code would simply be:

```
a(a>100)=0
```

However, in my case I need to take the third matrix of my 3D matrix, which would be a(:,:,3).
If I now try to use the same code:

```
a(:,:,3)(a(:,:,3)>100)=0
```

I get the message "()-indexing must appear last in an index expression."

Any idea on how I can express that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
 a(:,:,3) = (a(:,:,3)<100).*a(:,:,3);
```

?

Comment: @maupertius, sorry, I saw it working too..This corrected version is checked more carefully. my apologies.

Comment: @Acorbe Looks like your code is the way to go. However, I still get an error that says "Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.". This does not happen if I create a random matrix, but only with the specific matrix in my code (which happens to be a matrix of only integer values).

Comment: @maupertius then you require a cast, because the comparison casts to double I guess. It would be  `a(:,:,3) = int16((a(:,:,3)<100)).*a(:,:,3);`. Substitute `int16` with class of `int`s you are using (`int32`,`int64`,.., tested btw ;) )..

Comment: +1 now it works :) I have also found a way to make your original idea work :)

Comment: @Acorbe Works beautifully! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

You can use linear indexes for that:

```
id = find(A(:,:,3)>100)+2*size(A, 1)*size(A, 2);
A(id)=0
```

Alternatively, you can `reshape` array `A` to 2D and:

```
AA = reshape(A, 500*500, 3);
AA(AA(:,3)>100,3) = 0;
A = reshape(AA, 500, 500,3);
```

which uses the original code of Acorbe, but works for 2D matrices in contrast to 3D :)

Comment: +1 Nice!..I'll try to figure out if it is doable somehow without reshaping also in 3D.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another alternative:

```
A(cat(3, false(size(A,1),size(A,2),2), A(:,:,3)>100)) = 0;
```

Alternatively, you can assign an index variable in 3D like so:

```
id(:,:,3) = A(:,:,3)>100;
A(id) = 0;
```

which has a much more cleaner syntax.

Now for some speed tests:

```
clc, clear all

b = 250*rand(500,500, 3);

% Me 1
tic
for ii = 1:1e2
    A=b;
    clear id
    id = cat(3, false(size(A,1),size(A,2),2), A(:,:,3)>100);
    A(id) = 0;
end
toc

% Acorbe
tic
for ii = 1:1e2
    A=b;
    A(:,:,3) = (A(:,:,3)<100).*A(:,:,3);
end
toc

% angainor 1
tic
for ii = 1:1e2
    A=b;
    clear id
    id = find(A(:,:,3)>100) + 2*size(A, 1)*size(A, 2);
    A(id)=0;
end
toc

% Me 2
tic
for ii = 1:1e2
    A=b;
    clear id
    id(:,:,3) = A(:,:,3)>100;
    A(id) = 0;
end
toc

% angainor 2
tic
for ii = 1:1e2
    A=b;
    clear id
    AA = reshape(A, [], 3);
    AA(AA(:,3)>100,3) = 0;
    A = reshape(AA, size(A,1), size(A,2), 3);
end
toc
```

Results:

```
Elapsed time is 1.612787 seconds. % me #1
Elapsed time is 1.223496 seconds. % Acorbe
Elapsed time is 1.606858 seconds. % angainor #1
Elapsed time is 1.510153 seconds. % me #2
Elapsed time is 0.964423 seconds. % angainor #2
```

Seems the winner is angainor :)

Comment: Those speed contests... :) I have included another method. Would you be so kind to add it? :) Although I have no hopes.

Comment: @angainor: "I have no hopes"...yeah sure :p

Comment: can't upvote twice, sorry...now the point is try to do it avoiding the reshaping, i.e. working on the local copy..if that is possible..

Comment: @Acorbe well, reshaping only adds code, no real operations. It does not perform any memory allocation etc. It is just a change in how you view the matrix. So it is not that bad.